# ASP.NET and Azure AD - how to define behaviour is user is NOT in specified role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I have a "legacy" ASP.NET MVC 5.2 application that I'm retrofitting to use Azure AD auth. I've defined a couple of application roles in Azure and have got the basics working. What I'm trying to control is what happens when an authenticated user hits a method that's decorated with the Authorize attribute and a role that they don't have.

My intent is to have the whole application reliant on being authenticated and authorized in some respect, but certain functions only enabled for certain roles.

(Oh, and it's written in VB. Don't judge...)

My Startup.vb:

```
<Assembly: OwinStartup(GetType(Startup))>
Public Class Startup
    Private clientId As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AuthClientId")
    Private redirectUri As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AuthRedirectUri")
    Shared tenant As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AuthTenantId")
    Private authority As String = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AuthAuthority"), tenant)

    Public Sub Configuration(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
            .ClientId = clientId,
            .Authority = authority,
            .RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            .PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            .Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            .ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications With {
                .AuthenticationFailed = AddressOf OnAuthenticationFailed
            }
        })
    End Sub

    Private Function OnAuthenticationFailed(ByVal context As AuthenticationFailedNotification(Of OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions)) As Task
        context.HandleResponse()
        context.Response.Redirect("/Unauthorised?errormessage=" & context.Exception.Message)
        Return Task.FromResult(0)
    End Function
End Class
```

And an example of a decorated method in one of the controllers:

```
<Authorize(Roles:="Access.Full")>
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function
```

When hitting a method to which the user is not authorised, the application redirects back to the Microsoft sign-in page. If the user selects an account that isn't authorised, it loops back to the sign-in page with no additional information. I need to be able to interrupt that process and redirect back to an error page with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

By default, the built-in authorisation classes treat being unauthenticated and authenticated-but-not-authorised as the same state. To be able to handle them differently, create your own custom Authorization attribute class, inheriting AuthorizeAttribute and override the HandleUnauthorizedRequest method to handle two different conditions differently:

```
Public Class LLAuthorize
    Inherits AuthorizeAttribute

    Protected Overrides Sub HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext As AuthorizationContext)

        If filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
            'Authenticated, but not authorised - i.e. doesn't have the required role
            filterContext.Result = New RedirectResult("/Unauthorised/Role")
        Else
            'Not authenticated, so handle by default and send to the 
            MyBase.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```